# Possible to use AngularJS 2 dependency injection on server in an Angular-Meteor application?

Tags: angular-meteor, angular-universal

[Angular-Meteor](https://angular-meteor.com/) allows Meteor.JS apps to integrate with AngularJS.
[Angular-Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) allows AngularJS 2 code to run on the server in Node.JS, allowing both server-side rendering and use of Angular's dependency injection framework.

Is it possible to use the AngularJS 2 dependency injection framework in an Angular-Meteor application to allow the same patterns to be used across the full stack and promote code reuse? If so, how? Any seed applications?

Answer (score 0):

I was fortunate to find the answer to my own question in this very clear and simple article on [Using Angular Dependency Injection in Node](https://kevinphelps.me/blog/using-angular-dependency-injection-in-node), which was fairly straightforward to adapt to the Angular-Meteor `/server` setup. I mistakenly thought that the solution required Angular-Universal, but it works entirely with the standard `@angular/core`.